# Grunt: No such file or directory

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I have just started a new project and I'm setting up a gruntfile and it's showing an error. I'm only adding sass and it's showing an error.

It looks like it should work, according to me. 
Grunt exits with the error:

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - undefined

Are the file paths causing that error? Grunt creates the css file at `assets/stylesheets/styles.css` but it's empty.

Here's my code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    sass: {
            dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed',
          compass: true
        },
        files: {
          'assets/stylesheets/style.css': 'src/sass/style.scss'
        }
      }
        },
        watch: {
            sass: {
        files: 'src/sass/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}',
        tasks: ['sass']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch'] );
}
```

grunt -v output:

```
Running "sass" task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Verifying property sass.dist exists in config...OK
Files: [no src] -> assets/stylesheets/style.css
Options: style="compressed", compass
Command: sass  assets/stylesheets/style.css --style=compressed --compass
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - undefined
```

Comment: It's usually helpful to run the task with the verbose option (`-v`) in cases like this. What's the output with verbose?

Comment: @steveax thankyou, i've added the output to my original post

Comment: So, it's not finding the sass file that is spec'd in the files key, what does the file structure of your project look like? (`tree` with the level option is your friend here)

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the error on the last line of the verbose output.

`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - undefined`

Whenever I've seen this error come out of GruntJS it's been due to an issue with a file path. In this case, it's likely that there is an issue with the output path, `assets/stylesheets`.

Beyond that, such an issue could be due to security permission flags on your working directory. Try manually creating your desired directory structure first. Then try to run the task. If the error goes away, the likely cause of the issue is that Grunt (Node) does not have sufficient permission to write to the file system your project.

Hope that helps!